# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character 'xa0' in position 586: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, cx-oracle

I'm getting this error while inserting the data into the table. result_df has a column which contains different languages text in it and I tried to use encode('utf-8') but no use . 
I used following code:

```
result_df.Column_Name.str.encode('utf-8')
data1=result_df.values.tolist() 
conn = connection.__open__()
cursor = conn.cursor()
sqlstmt = 'SQL_stmt'
cursor.executemany(sqlstmt, data1). 
conn.commit()
```

any advices on this is appreciated

Comment: There is too much missing information to be able to answer your question. Please develop a standalone test case that demonstrates the problem and then we can help you with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using (encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8") parameters in connect method . my issue is resolved.

conn = cx.connect(user='username', password='****', dsn='dsn_data',encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")